# Why does calling Box::new twice without storing the result allocate the same heap address?

Tags: memory-management, rust

I have the following code snippet:

```
fn test() {
    let addr = Box::new(1024);
    println!("{:p}", addr);
}

fn main(){
    test();
    test();
}
```

```
0x7fd2fa402b70
0x7fd2fa402b70
```

As the documentation explains, `Box::new` will allocate memory on the heap and then place the argument into it. No matter how many times I call `test()`, the program prints an identical address.

Why does Rust allocate the same heap address, even if the code is in an `unsafe` block? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Yes, Box will free resource when dropped.

Comment: But what if my scenario is that my next human input is depends on previous console output of that heap address. Or cast this address to integer and store it into disk file for further use

Comment: @racaljk in those case, you presumably wouldn't have dropped the `Box` in the first place. When dropped, you free the memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you aren't storing the result beyond the `test` function, the allocated memory is immediately freed. This allows the memory allocator to reuse the same address by the time of the second call.

---

> I think current `Box::new` implementation have different behaviors from what I expect

Yes, that seems likely, but it's worth thinking about *why* you expect this certain behavior. To me, the demonstrated behavior makes sense.

> or at least we should comment this "optimization" on [`Box`es] rustdoc

This isn't an optimization of `Box`, by any means. The behavior to free the value as soon as it doesn't have an owner is part of the definition of the Rust language.

It *could* be considered an optimization of the underlying memory allocator in use at the moment. However, the allocator implementation makes sense to many programmers and it's not unique to Rust. For example, here's a similar program in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int32_t *v = malloc(sizeof(int32_t));
    printf("%p\n", (void *)v);
    free(v);
  }
}
```

```
% clang -std=c17 -Wpedantic -Wall alloc.c
% ./a.out
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
0x7f87c6401860
```

Note that the implementation of the memory allocator is what ultimately causes the same address to be returned; it's possible to write a memory allocator where that's not true.

Comment: I think current Box::new implementation have different behaviors from what I expect, or at least we should comment this "optimization" on its rustdoc.

Comment: @racaljk It's hardly an optimization. In fact it's exactly what I would expect. If you just create and free a single `i32` one million times in a row, do you expect they all have different addresses? That would be a massive waste of space.